# Understanding Text IO

Tags: sml, smlnj

My function is trying to read a textfile line by line and carry out a certain predefined function on each line called somefn and append the value of somefn to the function. The somefn is already defined above this and works fine.

```
fun extractline(infile:string)=
    let
    val insl=TextIO.inputLine(ins)
    case insl of
    NONE=> []
    |SOME(l)=>somefn(insl)::extractline(infile)
    in
    TextIO.closeIn(ins);
    end
;
```

I am having errors and cannot handle them.
I would appreciate some help.

Thank You.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, in `let ... in ... end` blocks, you place declarations you need between `let` and `i n`, and the resulting expression between `in` and `end`.

As such, you need your `case` expression placed between `in` and `end`.

You also never open the stream, `ins`. Make your function open the stream, and then work recursively on that stream in another function, however; you don't want to open the file for each recursive call.

You'll want something on this form:

```
fun extractline file =
  let
      val ins = TextIO.openIn file

      fun extractline_h () = (* do something with ins here *)
  in
      extractline_h () before
      TextIO.closeIn ins
  end
```

Then you make `extractline_h` be recursive, and build up the list in that.